# jquery- Hide a div after showing it for 10 secs.

Tags: jquery

I've a div

```
<div class="alert alert-success" id="details_saved" style="text-align:center;display:none;">
    <h4>Record Saved</h4>
</div>
```

Initially it's `display:none` , I want to show it after a record is saved.

I'm trying `$('#details_saved').show().delay(1500).hide()`

Its not happening.

Where I'm going wrong or any other method?

Comment: Use `setTimeout`. `delay` is only for queued operations, not synchronous operations like hide and show.

Comment: You can use the jquery toggle events to do this in better way.

Comment: @Bharatsoni - Can you please provide a demo. Thanks

Comment: @apaul34208 - I've seen this but it didnt worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a duration to make `delay()` work with `hide()` and `show()`

```
$('#details_saved').show(1).delay(1500).hide(1);
```

1 millisecond is not noticeable to the human eye, and it does even work when passing zero.

Comment: It shows and instantly goes way, even if I increase the delay value.

Comment: Works just fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/N8jPz/

Comment: What is 1 in show() and hide()?

Comment: It's the duration, 1 milliseconds, without that it's not an animated method, and delay() doesn't work unless you start messing with the FX queue directly

Comment: I've tried your jsfiddle, but in my case it goes off instantly. Why?

Comment: It shows the element for 1.5 seconds, then it dissapears, isn't that what you're trying to do ?

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for another delay -> http://jsfiddle.net/N8jPz/1/

Comment: No. it doesn't even stay for 1.5 secs. It goes off instantly.

Comment: I've just tested that fiddle in Chrome, IE, Opera and Firefox, and it works everywhere for me, so you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: It worked I was commiting a mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this to hide

```
        $('#details_saved').delay(1500).fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a queued based implementation for delay to work

```
$('#details_saved').show().delay(1500).queue(function(){
    $(this).hide()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QyUUT/)

[.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) will work only with a queue, methods which make used of animations internally uses the default `fx` queue. In this you can add a method to the fx queue after adding a delay so that that method will get called after the delay.

Comment: I've tried your jsfiddle, but in my case it goes off instantly. Why?

Comment: can you share the related code... or edit the fiddle to replicate the case

Comment: I tried in jsfiddle, sadly it works over there. but not in my code.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

> Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue.

Use:

```
$("#details_saved").show();
setTimeout(function() { $("#details_saved").hide(); }, 1500);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `delay` only affects animations.  When `show` or `hide` are called with no duration passed, they are not animations.  Therefore, the delay does not affect them.  You have two options, either pass a duration to `hide` (even 1ms is enough) or use `setTimeout` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#details_saved').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#details_saved').hide();
    },1500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
setTimeout(show_div, 10000);
setTimeout(hide_div, 20000);

funciton show_div(){
    $('#mybox').show();
}

funciton hide_div(){
    $('#mybox').hide();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try .fadeToggle() :

```
$(function() {
        $('#switch').on('click', function() {
            $('#customOverlay').delay(1000).fadeToggle();
        });
});
OR

$(function() {
        $('#switch').on('click', function() {
            $('#customOverlay').fadeToggle(1000);
        });
});
The other answers that only use .delay() and .toggle won't work because .delay() only applies to the animation queue and .toggle() doesn't animate, while .fadeToggle() does.
```